# How to override the screenOrientation property of an activity which is in library

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

The title of this question is not exactly reflects my question I have trimmed it because it went too lengthy. Sorry for my bad English too.

Okay,

I am using a library which has an activity, I am using that activity in my app. The orientation of that activity is working fine in tablets i.e., both landscape and portrait but in phones it sticks to portrait mode.

When I have seen the Manifest file of that library its like

```
<activity
   android:name="DrawingActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
   android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
   android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
```

In the thread [Android Orentation Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974126/android-orentation-changes). I came to know it should like android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" to work.

Now I am trying to override the screenOrientation property of the activity as said [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Override-an-attribute-coming-from-a-library)

using `tools:replace` attribute but still its not working. Please can anybody help me to solve this issue.

This is how I'm trying to achieve.

```
<activity
   android:name="DrawingActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
   android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
   android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
   tools:replace="android:screenOrientation">
```

If my question is not clear/too broad please let me know I'll edit my question.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tools:node="merge"`, for example:

```
<activity android:name="DrawingActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
    tools:node="merge">
</activity>
```

this node will be merged with the existing one and overrides any duplicates.

for more details about this refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
   android:name="DrawingActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
   android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
   android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
   tools:replace="screenOrientation">
```

Dont use `android:screenOrientation` instead use `screenOrientation`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

> tools:node="replace"

In your case it'd be:

```
<activity  
   android:name="DrawingActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
   tools:node="replace" />
```

It will replace any attr added on the library which in this case will be 'screenOrientation' from 'unspecified' to 'fullSensor'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<activity android:name="DrawingActivity"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Import library as module instead of using Gradle, so you can change Code